# What does "The field xxx is never used" mean?

Tags: c#

My code file has many classes. Most of the fields are never used, in that they are not referenced in any other code, yet. However, there is only **one** field that generates a "The field is never used" warning. What does this really mean?

The field happens to be the first one in the first class in the file. I thought maybe only the first one in the file generates a warning, so I moved the class further down but the warning is still on that field. The field name is `mids` and I checked and it's not a C# reserved word.

It so happens that this field is giving me trouble when I am trying to deserialize a Json string of the class.

Comment: Why do you have unused fields in the first place?

Comment: What about access modifiers of these fields? Are all of them `public` except the only one generating warning is `private`? Generally compiler doesn't generates such a warning for public field since it can't determine if the field is being used in "outer" code.

Comment: Instead of just describing what the code looks like, can you produce a complete example which actually demonstrates the problem.  Also, what does "giving me trouble" mean?  What is the *actual* problem?

Comment: You mean [this compiler warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z62k595w.aspx)? is is a private field by any chance, whereas the others are public?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev and Rhumborl Thanks.  That led me to the solution. That's what an expert is. See http://stackoverflow.com/users/936293/old-geezer?tab=profile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning comes from static code analysis and is an indicator for code smell. Since you have not given us the code in question I will take a wild guess and assume that `mids` is the only `private` field, while the rest is `internal` or `public`.

Comment: Yes, this is the only field that is `private`. My eye scan wasn't good enough to pick it out because this was `List<string> mids` whereas all the other fields were simple value types (`public string xxx`) and the alignment fooled me.

Answer (score 2):

This warning means exactly what it says.  The field `mids` is never used anywhere else in the code.  By used, it means nowhere is the field value set and nowhere is the field value accessed.

In essence, the field is dead code and the IDE/compiler is informing you the field is useless and can be removed without any harm to the remainder of the code.